# Simple If Statement Not Working Comparing Strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, if-statement

I am just simply trying to navigate to a webpage and check availability. When I find the availability status and try and see if it is "In Stock." then I want to perform some action (in the example print "Found"). When I test it the variable `InStockCheck` does not seem to register as a string. I believe that when I use

```
InStockCheck = driver.find_element_by_id("availability").text
```

that it is not a string?

Current output is:

```
InStock.
Yellow
```

Desired output:

```
InStock.
Found
```

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

import bs4 as bs

FoundItem = "Nope"
driver = webdriver.Safari()

while (FoundItem == "Nope"):

    #driver = webdriver.Safari()
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B01MUAGZ49/ref=s9_acsd_top_hd_bw_bHp5rsB_c_x_w?pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-3&pf_rd_r=34J7S43PK58HEWFWQRCY&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1a0d15fb-8f11-58d0-9960-246ad05b4dc8&pf_rd_i=16329250011")

    #SourceCodeTest = driver.page_source

    #Soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(SourceCodeTest, "lxml")

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "availability")))
    InStockCheck = driver.find_element_by_id("availability").text
    InStockCheck = InStockCheck.replace(" ","")
    print(InStockCheck)

    if InStockCheck == "InStock.":
        print("Found")
    else:
        print("Yellow")

print("Pink")
```

Comment: Have you checked for whitespace or other invisible characters?

Comment: yeah you could use `InStockCheck  = InStockCheck.strip()` it seems to have a linefeed when you print it.

Comment: @pvg I don't know how to "check for invisible characters". The solution that Jean stated worked but for my future debugging, how would I check for invisible characters?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Is a line feed the same as a line break? Your solution to use .strip() worked perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @Aiden you could iterate over the string character by character and compare them. You can check if the lengths match. Essentially anything that verifies that strings that _appear_ equal actually contain the same thing. The `strip` thing works because the most common case is a trailing newline and `strip` gets rid of that.

Comment: @pvg That makes sense, check the string length visible vs iterated length. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You can just check yourself using `print` before adding any if-else , check the string and then add the condition according to that string :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

import bs4 as bs
import sys
FoundItem = "Nope"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

while (FoundItem == "Nope"):

    #driver = webdriver.Safari()
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B01MUAGZ49/ref=s9_acsd_top_hd_bw_bHp5rsB_c_x_w?pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-3&pf_rd_r=34J7S43PK58HEWFWQRCY&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1a0d15fb-8f11-58d0-9960-246ad05b4dc8&pf_rd_i=16329250011")

    #SourceCodeTest = driver.page_source

    #Soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(SourceCodeTest, "lxml")

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "availability")))
    InStockCheck = driver.find_element_by_id("availability").text
    InStockCheck_ori = InStockCheck.strip()
    print(InStockCheck_ori)
    InStockCheck1 = InStockCheck.replace(" ","")
    print(InStockCheck1)
```

output:

```
In Stock.
InStock.
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have Safari, so I used Chrome.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

This gives the desired result for some reason. Be sure to give some condition to break out of the while loop. For instance,

```
# other imports
import time

# other code
numberOfRetries = 0

while (FoundItem == "Nope"):
    # other code

    if InStockCheck == "InStock.":
        print("Found")
        break
    elif numberOfTries > 4:
        print("Not found after waiting for 5 seconds")
        break
    else:
        print("Yellow")
        numberOfRetries = numberOfRetries + 1
        time.sleep(1)

print("Pink")
```